# Tags search regular expression

Tags: regex

PROBLEM: to find all the sometags and list them down with the text within the sometags if any

Pattern of the sometag:

```
<sometag>text1</sometag>
<sometag text2>text1</sometag>
<sometag
text2>text1</sometag>
```

text1, text2 may be empty

EXAMPLE:

```
Info about Leela <sometag xml:lang="en" lang="en"><b><sometag>Turanga Leela
</sometag></b></sometag><sometag>Super</sometag><sometag>girl</sometag>
```

MY SOLUTION:

```
<sometag([\w\d\s:=\"<>]+)?<\/sometag>(<\/b>)?(<\/sometag>)?
```

RESULT:

1. `<sometag xml:lang="en" lang="en"><b><sometag>Turanga Leela
   </sometag></b></sometag>`
2. `<sometag>Super</sometag>`
3. `<sometag>girl</sometag>`

QUESTION/CONCERN:

Why is not < sometag>Turanga Leela
< /sometag> showing up?

Comment: What's the expected output and what language are you using?

Comment: Java - As stated in the QUESTION/CONCERN part ABOVE - I am asking why does NOT my proposed regular expression also get the <sometag>Turanga Leela </sometag> TAG?

Comment: Sometimes `<sometag >` tag has some attributes, do you want to achieve attributes?

Comment: You have a line break in your input

Comment: @Shafizadeh Yes, as you can see in RESULTS - under 1 the options are covered.

Comment: @GalAbra, is not this covered by \s+ already?

Comment: My big concern is that even here https://regex101.com if I simply put "<span>Turanga Leela
</span>" in the TEST STRING and "<sometag([\w\d\s:=\"<>]+)?<\/sometag>(<\/b>)?(<\/sometag>)?" as REGULAR EXPRESSION the match that I want works out while in the bigger text it does not - where is the catch?

Comment: Using regex101, I get `<sometag xml:lang="en" lang="en"><b><sometag>Turanga Leela
</sometag></b></sometag>` for the first match. It won't identify `<sometag>Turanga Leela
</sometag>` as another match as it is already enclosed in first, begin "consumed" then, as regex engine will position immediately after first match.